# Should I edit the code sample of a question?

Tags: discussion

In some cases, I have found that the code sample provided in a question is not minimal showing a particular issue. Is it advisable to make subtle changes to the code to make it more readable/precise or leave it to the OP?

Comment: That type of edit is almost certainly going to get rejected for changing the intent of the OP. Note that the people reviewing your edit aren't necessarily experts in the language/libraries being used in the question. They have to decide whether you *could* be changing the intent, and editing out code looks like you're doing that. Leave it to the OP to fix it.

Comment: If it's not clearly readable, close-vote as 'unclear what you are asking' and move on.   There is no question shortage, and so you should apply what time you have available to answering good questions, not propping-up posters who can not or will not post code with sufficient quality fo SO.

Comment: @MartinJames To add to your point,  this is one case where scale matters.  If someone dumps 500 lines of code for a problem with 10 lines, I close every time, but when there's a 30 line example that you could show with 10, I wouldn't close it, I'd either leave it or possibly fix it (since my edits don't go through /review).

Comment: There are some things that are somewhat OK to change in code, though. If there are unnecessary comments, like the Netbeans default license header, edit it out.